# embedded form by repeated script

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am adding a Hubspot embedded form to a page, the form is added by script. I use an onMounted so that when the form is displayed and it does it well, the problem is that, when I leave that component where the form is and re-enter, it adds another space to the form which does not have any input, it only occupies the space and below it, it already adds the correct form, how can I solve this? Tried unUnmonted and conditionals, but failed to resolve. This is the code where I add the form:

```
onMounted(() => {
      let script = document.createElement('script')
      script.setAttribute('src', 'https://js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js')

      document.head.appendChild(script)

      script.addEventListener("load", () => {
          if (window.hbspt) {
              window.hbspt.forms.create({
                  region: "",
                  portalId: "423423423",
                  formId: "65363456-456-23g22-3423-g34g3f363g",
                  target: "#content-form"
              });

          }
      })
  })
```

this is what it leaves me in the HTML, the first iframe is empty but it occupies the space
[image]

Comment: `Tried unUnmonted` what did you try in onUnmounted, and did you do unUnmounted or onUnmounted? Perhaps you did it wrong - you should possibly remove the iframe? by the way, if this is an SPA, every time you go to this page, the script will be loaded *again* - check the document head, is there multiple `https://js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js`?

Comment: yes, I used onUnmounted, but it doesn't work, it keeps showing me the same thing in the HTML. If there are several scripts in the head, but how can I remove them, the problem is with the appendChild, right?

Comment: `I used onUnmounted` ... but what did you DO in `onUnmounted`?

Comment: copy the same from onMounted, still try this: `document.head.removeChild(script)`, but I get an error

Comment: see answer - as I suggested in the first comment `Perhaps you did it wrong` :p - you don't need to remove the script, once it's loaded, keep it loaded, it's no problem to do so, you want to remove the `iframe` though - and only load the script if it hasn't been loaded before - in fact, you probably could load the script when your App loads, therefore the first time you load the page it's used on, you won't have a delay while that script is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The solution that worked was a variation on the full answer below
> i.e. all that was required is:

```
onMounted(() => {
    document.querySelector('#content-form>iframe")?.remove();
    ... rest of code unchanged
});
```

---

Here's a guess

rewrite `onMounted` to load the script only once

```
onMounted(() => {
      const loadForm = () => {
          window.hbspt.forms.create({
              region: "",
              portalId: "423423423",
              formId: "65363456-456-23g22-3423-g34g3f363g",
              target: "#content-form"
          });
      };
      if (window.hbspt) { // script already loaded
          return loadForm();
      }
      let script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = 'https://js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js';

      document.head.appendChild(script);

      script.addEventListener("load", () => {
          if (window.hbspt) {
              loadForm();
          }
      });
});
```

`onUnmounted` should just remove the content of the `target` element

```
onUnmounted(() => {
    document.querySelector('#content-form>iframe")?.remove();
});
```

---

As an alternative, if you load `https://js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js` in your `index.html` instead, then `onMounted` only needs

```
onMounted(() => {
    window.hbspt.forms.create({
        region: "",
        portalId: "423423423",
        formId: "65363456-456-23g22-3423-g34g3f363g",
        target: "#content-form"
    });
});
```

and `onUnmounted` would remain the same

Comment: still the same hehe, when entering for the first time, it shows me the form (iframe) when leaving and entering again it shows me two forms :/

Comment: OK, can you confirm `onUnmounted` is executing? I take it the div with id=content-form is in your code, not something that is added by hbspt? can you try adding `document.querySelector('#content-form>iframe")?.remove();` to the beginning of `onMounted`?

Comment: It's what I did, and it can't find that element? I still look for it with console.log and it returns null

Comment: yet, when you create the form, it creates 2? does it create 3 the next time, then 4, 5, etc every time you enter that page?

Comment: When entering the component for the first time, it creates only one form (iframe), when leaving and re-entering it creates another one, and it only creates two, it does not go beyond that

Comment: does the number in `id=hs-form-iframe-` keep going up?

Comment: yes :/, when loading for the first time it is `id=hs-form-iframe-0`, and the form is fine, when leaving and re-entering the first form(id=hs-form-iframe-0) it is empty and the second is the full one which changes its value from 2 to 2 , id=hs-form-iframe-2, id=hs-form-iframe-4, ...

Comment: I see that the `document.querySelector('#broker-form>iframe')?.remove()` as not selecting it, I guess this is the problem

Comment: @luis - you accepted the answer? What changed?

Comment: The code stayed the same as in the question, just add `document.querySelector('#content-form>iframe")?.remove()` to the top and it worked hehe, Thank you very much

Comment: @luis - so, you'll be loading the script on every mounted? that's wasteful :p

Comment: @luis - I've updated the answer so that future readers will understand what actually made the code work :p